# Can't succed to write in a database

Tags: android, sqlite, gps

Hy!
I'm trying for days now to create an application that receives GPS data and has to store it in a Sqlite database.I've created the database and I also have an GeoPoints Array list that I put in my geopoints.The GPS data is simulated with the help of a KML file.
Now,my problem is that even though I succeded to display the map that is updated with the new locations while I try to read from the Sqlite database and display on the screen the geopoints I get nothing-no text displayed on the screen.

Here is my code:

```
public class screen4 extends MapActivity 
{    
    private LocationManager lm;
    private LocationListener locationListener;
    private MyLocationOverlay myLocOverlay;

    private MapView mapView;
    private MapController mc;

List<GeoPoint> geoPointsArray = new ArrayList<GeoPoint>();
    int latitude;
    int longitude;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.screen4); 
        lm = (LocationManager) 
            getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);    

        locationListener = new MyLocationListener();

        lm.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER,0,0,locationListener);

        mapView = (MapView) findViewById(R.id.mapview1);
        mapView.setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
        mc = mapView.getController();
        initMyLocation();
       DBAdapter db=new DBAdapter(this);
       db.createDatabase();
       db.openDataBase();
      for (int i = 0; i < geoPointsArray.size()-1; i++)
       {
           GeoPoint loc=geoPointsArray.get(i);

          db.insertData(Integer.toString(loc.getLongitudeE6()),Integer.toString(loc.getLatitudeE6()),null,null,null);


       }
      Cursor c=db.getAllData();
     if(c.moveToFirst()) 
     {
      do{
          DisplayTitle(c);
      }while(c.moveToNext());

     }
     if(c!=null&&!c.isClosed()){
        db.close();
     }

    }

    private void initMyLocation() {
        myLocOverlay = new MyLocationOverlay(this, mapView);
        myLocOverlay.enableMyLocation();
        mapView.getOverlays().add(myLocOverlay);

    }
    public void DisplayTitle(Cursor c)
    {
        Toast.makeText(this, 
                "longitude: " + c.getString(0) + "\n" +
                "latitude: " + c.getString(1) + "\n",
                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();        
    } 
    private class MyLocationListener implements LocationListener 
    {
        @Override
        public void onLocationChanged(Location loc) {
            if (loc != null) {                         
                latitude=(int) (loc.getLatitude()* 1E6);
                longitude=(int) (loc.getLongitude()* 1E6);



           GeoPoint p = new GeoPoint(latitude,longitude);
           geoPointsArray.add(p);

                mc.animateTo(p);
              mc.setZoom(17);                
                mapView.invalidate();
                mapView.setSatellite(true);
           }

        }

        @Override
        public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        }

        @Override
        public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) { 

        }
        @Override
        public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) { 

        }
    }

    protected boolean isRouteDisplayed() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return false;
    } 

     }
```

I did debug to my code line by line and as I get to this line(the first one):

```
 for (int i = 0; i < geoPointsArray.size()-1; i++)
       {
           GeoPoint loc=geoPointsArray.get(i);
           db.insertData(Integer.toString(loc.getLongitudeE6()),Integer.toString(loc.getLatitudeE6()),null,null,null);
       }
```

the debugger jumps this snippet...now to me that means that I have no point in my geoPointsArray and I have  nothing to store in the data base and there is nothing to read from Sqlite.
Can someone help me please with some ideas.Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In general `if` guards for arrays should be `i < size` and not `i < size - 1`.

To avoid mistakes in guards altogether you might use:

```
for (GeoPoint loc : geoPointsArray) {
    ....
```

instead.

**Edit** - Also, your database access only seems to be performed in `onCreate`. You need to do this in your `LocationListener` if you expect it to be called when you get updates.

`onCreate` is only called once when your activity is created. You should open your database here and then do your accesses when you actually get the data.

Comment: Thank u!I did that but still no text displayed and I can't figure out if I have something written in my database.You  see I'm receiving GPS data,while I ask for updates using

Comment: lm.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER,0,0,locationListener);...I also try to put the data in a List Array and in the same time afterwards I want to display it.....it's a bit over me

Comment: oki,thank u.I'll try to modify it right now...I hope this will get it fixed

Comment: I'm facing another problem:I do this  DBAdapter db=new DBAdapter(this); in my OnCreate and when I try to do db.insertData(Integer.toString(loc.getLongitudeE6()),Integer.toString(loc.getLatitudeE6()),null,null,null); in my LocationChanged() it doesn't know who "db" is....how can I make it global?

Comment: define it as an instance variable in your class. In other words, on the line before `onCreate` do: `DBAdapter db;` and then change your other line to `db = new DBAdapter(this);`

Comment: Now I get force close ....if I've done what u said,where should I close my db?If I do it where is now,my db gets closed before I get to write in it the whole data,isn't it?

Comment: You should close your db in `onDestroy`: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#ActivityLifecycle

Comment: There is a little tiny problem:if I run my application it works fine,but in the moment I try to send GPS data from DDMS and my LocationChanged(WHERE I HAVE THE ACCES TO MY DATABASE) is activated I get force close...Can u help me with this too,I'd really appreciate.Thank you in advance:D

Comment: You should probably make a new question, repost your current code and describe the problem you're now having.